# How to run a function at a certain UTC time?

Tags: python, datetime, time, utc, schedule

I'm writing a small script that starts a function at a certain time (16:00 for example), the problem is that my script obviously works based on the time of the computer, but I need it to use UTC, so that it can be used regardless of where a person lives.

I have found several libraries that do the job, but given my inexperience I can't seem to match things up ...

Here is an example of how the script works. I need to do the same thing but with UTC time.

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
   print("make some stuff....")

schedule.every().day.at("16:00:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#does-schedule-support-time-zones): ***Does schedule support time zones?** - Vanilla schedule doesn’t support time zones at the moment. If you need this functionality please check out @imiric’s work here. He added time zone support to schedule using python-dateutil."*

Comment: Could you not convert the desired UTC time to local time using the offset and then use that in the schedule.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver what if DST changes the UTC offset ?

Comment: If you where using an actual timezone like my local one `america/los angeles` then the offset would change correctly at the `DST` changeovers.

Comment: Thank you  
Adrian Klaver for the answers, Anyway I don't know if I have explained myself well, my English is not the best.
However what I have to do is run a command similar to this
schedule.every (). day.at ("16:00:00"). do (job)
But it does the job (in this case at 4pm) regardless of where a person lives. 
I don't have to use schedule but I have to find a way to do it ...
But given my inexperience, I struggle a bit ..
Thanks everyone for the answers